# Identificar letras com acento e imprimir um aviso

Tags: c++, string, algoritmo

Eu preciso fazer um programa que aceite apenas letras sem acento, e pra isso eu estou tentando fazer algo que identifique uma letra com acento e então imprima um aviso sobre o erro, porém quando eu digito alguma letra com acento ele simplesmente termina o programa.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ptb");

    string palavra;
    string comAcento = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûù";
    bool palavra_valida;
    palavra_valida = true;

    do
    {
        cout << "Informe uma palavra: ";
        cin >> palavra;

        for (int a = 0; a < palavra.size(); a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < comAcento.size(); b++)
            {
                if (palavra[a] == comAcento[b])
                {
                cout << "Não digite letras com acento";
                palavra_valida = false;
                }
            }
        }

    } while (palavra_valida == !true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil verificar se cada caractere está dentre os caracteres representados na tabela ASCII?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Não quero mexer demais porque pode ser exercício que pede para fazer desta forma.

Para fazer isso direto assim na `main()` se torna bem complicado, teria que fazer `if` com `break` em cada nível, além de usar *flag* que é mais feio que `goto`.

Para não complicar muito seria interessante usar um `goto`, o que não costuma ser recomendado, inclusive a performance seria muito maior por não ter que ficar verificando outros caracteres quando já sabe que a palavra é inválida. Seria algo assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ptb");
inicio:
    string palavra;
    cout << "Informe uma palavra: ";
    cin >> palavra;
    for (int a = 0; a < palavra.size(); a++) {
        string comAcento = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûù";
        for (int b = 0; b < comAcento.size(); b++) {
            if (palavra[a] == comAcento[b]) {
                cout << "Não digite letras com acento";
                goto inicio;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yzmRKw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/HasAccentcpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/HasAccent.cpp).

Se ainda não quiser usar `goto` veja como fica. Algumas pessoas preferem, embora seja mais confuso de acompanhar. Nunca conheci um programador onde pude avaliar a boa qualidade do que produz que prefira isso, mas encontrei algumas pessoas experientes que gostam assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ptb");
    bool palavra_valida;
    do {
        palavra_valida = true;
        string palavra;
        cout << "Informe uma palavra: ";
        cin >> palavra;
        for (int a = 0; a < palavra.size(); a++) {
            string comAcento = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûù";
            for (int b = 0; b < comAcento.size(); b++) {
                if (palavra[a] == comAcento[b]) {
                    cout << "Não digite letras com acento";
                    palavra_valida = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!palavra_valida) break;
        }
    } while (!palavra_valida);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/50wk9X). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/HasAccent2cpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/HasAccent2.cpp).

Mas se usar uma função (que é o maior `goto` de todos, mas é uma forma que organiza melhor) fica muito mais estruturado e legível:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool temAcento(string palavra) {
    for (int a = 0; a < palavra.size(); a++) {
        string comAcento = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûù";
        for (int b = 0; b < comAcento.size(); b++) {
            if (palavra[a] == comAcento[b]) {
                cout << "Não digite letras com acento";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ptb");
    while (true) {
        string palavra;
        cout << "Informe uma palavra: ";
        cin >> palavra;
        if (!temAcento(palavra)) break;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kdAu8s). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/HasAccent3cpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/HasAccent3.cpp).